# Problem with SSL certificate

Tags: 7, .htaccess, configuration, ssl, http-request

I just enable SSL certificate for my domain.
I added that in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.com*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And:

```
# HSTS.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</IfModule>

# Cookie secure.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure
</IfModule>
```

And I changed the line in my settings.php file:

```
$base_url = 'https://www.domainename.com';
```

And :

```
$conf['https'] = FALSE;
```

All my https site displays well with the little green padlock, but the following errors appear in the dashboard drupal :

[image]

[image]

The Piwik module displays the following error:

> Message d'erreur The validation of
>   "https://analytics.s1biose.com/piwik.php" failed with error "Error opening socket ssl://analytics.s1biose.com:443"
>   (HTTP code 0).

[image]

Comment: Those two things are not related. Your SSL certificate is for _inbound_ traffic, the errors are complaining about not being able to send _outbound_ traffic.

Comment: @Clive ok, since this is the activation of SSL. I can not think of or comes the error. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: @Clive it comes right SSL, because if I go to https to http, the disparraissent errors. I do not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: You'll need to check what about your server configuration is causing that to happen, it's not Drupal doing it

Answer (score 2):

There are some known issues with Drupal 7.x in some server configurations particularly around PHP 5.6 and OpenSSL 0.9x due to [changes in how PHP verifies SSL certificates](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#refsect1-context.ssl-changelog). [Acquia has some notes](https://docs.acquia.com/articles/php-56-upgrades-generate-http-request-status-fails-messages) about the cause and options (including a core patch to try to address some instances of the problem but read the whole article before considering that option).

On shared hosting you'll likely want to try the [Alternative HTTP Client module](https://www.drupal.org/project/alt_http_client) to see if it resolves the notice.

Comment: can you tell me if the configuration described above is ok ?

Comment: Given the error message it appears something is wrong. You have PHP 5.6 so the references I included may apply but you'd have to check the rest of your setup (like SNI and OpenSSL version). The module included in the Acquia article may also be worth trying to see if it can resolve the problem.

Comment: thank you for the information but I'm on a shared server at ovh

Comment: If you're on shared hosting, you're at the mercy of whatever server config they put in place for you. By the looks of it, their config for secure incoming connections also includes blocking outgoing connections. Getting in touch with them directly is probably the only way you'll get this solved, something will probably need to change at their end

Comment: The Alternative HTTP Client module is worth trying. I haven't used it, but in a limited hosting environment it may be your best option.

Comment: Hello, can you explain me how to install this module? (I'm on a shared server with php 5.6)

Comment: Extract the module to sites/all/modules in your site directory, then add this to the bottom of settings.php `$conf['drupal_http_request_function'] = 'alt_drupal_http_request';`. For more on how to install modules see https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes

Comment: @cam8001 I installed the module but it does not work for me. Currently I have no solution to my problem. Here is a discussion with the module creator https://www.drupal.org/node/2781609